# HTML Horizontal Scroll not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having trouble getting the horizontal scroll bar to show up. I can still scroll horizontally with the track pad and everything is formatted correctly but the bar itself is not showing up so that you can use it to move horizontally on the table with the mouse. Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

HTML - Through React Framework

```
{/* Order */}
            <div className ="order">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>Farm</td>
                            <td>Field</td>
                            <td>W/O</td>
                            <td>Job</td>
                            <td>APA</td>
                            <td>Acres</td>
                            <td>Status</td>
                            <td>Solution</td>
                            <td>Date Ordered</td>
                            <td>Date Sampled</td>
                            <td>Date Billed</td>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Years Billed</td>
                            <td>Split 1</td>
                            <td>Split 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    
                        {orders.map((order, num) => {
                            let splitOne = ""
                            let splitTwo = ""
                            if(order.split_one_name.length > 1){
                                splitOne = `${order.split_one_name} - ${order.split_one_share}`
                            }
                            if(order.split_two_name.length > 1){
                                splitTwo = `${order.split_two_name} - ${order.split_two_share}`
                            }

                            return (
                            <tr key={order.id}>
                                <td>{order.id}</td>
                                <td>{order.farm}</td>
                                <td>{order.field}</td>
                                <td>{startInputMode(order.wo_num, num, 'wo_num')}</td>
                                <td>{startInputMode(order.job_num, num, 'job_num')}</td>
                                <td>{order.firstname + " " + order.lastname}</td>
                                <td>{order.acres}</td>
                                <td>{startInputMode(order.status, num, 'status')}</td>
                                <td>{order.solution}</td>
                                <td>{order.date_ordered.slice(0,10)}</td>
                                <td>{startInputMode(order.date_sampled, num, 'date_sampled')}</td>
                                <td>{startInputMode(order.date_billed, num, "date_billed")}</td>
                                <td>{order.price}</td>
                                <td>{order.years_billed}</td>
                                <td>{splitOne}</td>
                                <td>{splitTwo}</td>
                            </tr>)
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 100px;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
  
  .order {
    display: block;
    grid-area: orders;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    max-height: 520px;
    
    overflow: scroll;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
   }
  
   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: grey;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table css, change `overflow: scroll` to `overflow: auto`.

Then remove `height: 0px` from `::-webkit-scrollbar`.

[::-webkit-scrollbar Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

Comment: I tried that but I am still not getting a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Here is a working sandbox with the changes I made. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-browser-zf6xy?file=/styles.css